# How i can get the route param in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How i can get the route param in react native.

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('SingleTour', { item } )}
```

Comment: Describe more about your question. Is you need to pass item and get it from SingleTour page ?

Comment: Take a look over here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query-params

Comment: which version are you using for react navigation?

Comment: @MayankPandav 0.61

Comment: are you sure im not asking for react native ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way you can send the item  `eg index.js`

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('SingleTour', { item } )}>
    <Text>SingleTour</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

in `SingleTour.js` you can get this item like this

```
const { item } = this.props.route.params;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need to pass param with navigation and set param to the new screen's state.

Assuming that this is your onPress event on base screen

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('SingleTour', { item } )}
```

So this is how you set param in new screen's state

**SingleTour.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

export default class SingleTour extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item : this.props.navigation.state.params.item,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

Hope you have clear about this :)

Comment: 4 or 5 same way

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution.

```
        onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
        }}
```

If any problem occurs, you can refer to this  [Official Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)
Refer this Expo Snack [Online Demo](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Passing%20parameters%20to%20routes%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%405.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%405.0.4%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%401.5.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%401.4.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%400.6.0%2Creact-native-screens%402.0.0-alpha.12&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fpassing-params.js)